# Add NetTopologySuite when configuring Oracle Dbcontext with Ef Core 5

Tags: oracle, .net-5, nettopologysuite

I have a project with .Net 5.0 and Oracle is the databse provider. The version of the packages are:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="NetTopologySuite.IO.Oracle" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.21.3" />
```

I want to configure the DbContext of Oracle, and the 'AddDbContext' to accept the use of topology, so using fluent API I could create a migration with a geometry column, like this:

```
builder.Property(p => p.WKTSRID)
       .HasColumnType("SDO_GEOMETRY")
       .HasConversion(w => WKTToSdoGeometry(w.WKT, w.SRID), r => SdoGeometryToWKT(r))
```

If not, the migration shows an error saying that the property 'WKTSRID' has a type that isn't supported by teh provider, and doesn't map to the type 'SDO_GEOMETRY' of Oracle

The **DbContext needs to keep** the compatibility with the 11 version, with the method **.UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11")**

Is there any way to achieve this (without using Devart)?

**Edit:**

I've also tested directly with a NetTopologySuite.IO.Sdo.SdoGeometry property. Having my entity class like this:

```
public class MyGeo  { public SdoGeometry MySdoGeo { get; set; } }
```

And my EF configuration as either of this two:

```
builder.Property(p => p.MySdoGeo).HasColumnType("SDO_GEOMETRY")
builder.Property(p => p.MySdoGeo)
```

I obtain the same error:

> The property 'MyGeo.MySdoGeo' is of type 'SdoGeometry' which is not
> supported by the current database provider. Either change the property
> CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or
> by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I've also tried using the type 'NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Geometry' and setting the property type and the conversion on the EF configuration as follows, but doesn't work:

```
public class MyGeo  { public Geometry MySdoGeo { get; set; } }

builder.Property(p => p.MySdoGeo)
       .HasColumnType("SDO_GEOMETRY")
       .HasConversion(a => Geo2SdoGeometry(a), d => SdoGeometry2Geo(d))
```

If there is any way to add the use of topology in the DbContext configuration? (As it seems to be not supported, Could you give any hint to add the missing support?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .NET 5 reached End Of Life over a year ago. It was only a single-year support version. EOL means there won't be any fixes, not even security patches, and all vendors and open source maintainers are free to just drop support for it, which they already started doing. The Long Term Support version is .NET 6, supported until 2024

Comment: As for the question itself, what's the actual error? Post the exact, full error text. The exact error text can be googled to find possible fixes or Github issues

Comment: As for `without using Devart` there's a reason people prefer Devart's drivers over Oracle's for the last 20 years. Oracle drivers are huge, slow and buggy. Oracle makes no money from either the drivers or the .NET environments they run on so they don't pay a lot of attention to them

Comment: I cannot update the project to .net 6, even if .net 5 is an 'EOL' version and I can't use Devart, part of it's because doesn't admit UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11").

Comment: As for the error is this:

The property 'WKTSRID' is of type 'MyGeo' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: Consider what you're saying: you're asked to call an unsupported database from an unsupported runtime and use features that require explicit support from ORM and database providers. Which don't exist, precisely because that database version is unsupported. You'll have to either skip that feature (migrations) or add the missing support yourself.

Comment: `NetTopologySuite.IO.Oracle` is a package that allows reading and writing Oracle Spatial data using ADO.NET, not an EF Core Provider so adding it doesn't add mapping or migration support to EF Core. One option would be to *not* use automatic migrations but write them explicitly. Another is to not use migrations at all, but generate change scripts instead. You probably have to do that anyway because I doubt any Oracle DBA would allow an application to just generate tables and columns. You may be looking for a feature you just aren't allowed to use

Comment: EF Core creates migrations for Oracle Provider, as I'm using them without prlobems, but doesn't know how to map topology data, that's my problem.
I want to know if my aim is possible, even if i've to add the missing support, and if that's the case how can i do it. But I don't want to stop using migrations, neither at all or partially

Thanks for your help

Comment: DevArt's dbConnect does support Oracle 11g. Why not use it? As for adding support for NTS to Oracle's EF Core provider, you have to actually modify that provider and recompile it. You can't just add a mapping. It's Oracle's provider that converts LINQ queries to SQL. `HasConversion` tells EF Core how to convert a raw database value to an application type value but doesn't tell it how to use the unknown database type.

Comment: It's a requeriment of the project not to use DevArt, so please, stop advicing it

Comment: You didn't mention that restriction, only that you couldn't target Oracle 11g with Devart. Which is quite possible. That doesn't change the fact you can't just make Oracle's EF provider work with NTS just by adding a value conversion. What you could do is load the geometries as text and use a `NotMapped` property that converts them to NTS geometries. To use spatial queries you'll have to use `FromSqlRaw` and `FromSqlInterpolated` to create a base query using spatial operations then apply other LINQ operators